# LZW routine in Haskell using Monads

Tags: haskell, monads, lzw

I'm trying to implement LZW compression in Haskell using Monads, here is my code so far with test cases:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Data.Char (chr, ord)
import Data.List (isPrefixOf, maximumBy)
import Data.Function
import Test.QuickCheck

type Dictionary = [String]

dictionary :: Dictionary
dictionary = [[chr x] | x <- [0..127]]


test_dictionary =
  [ map ord (concat dictionary) == [0..127]
  , all (\str -> length str == 1) dictionary
  ]

prefixes :: String -> Dictionary -> [(Int, String)]
prefixes str dict = [(x, dict!!x) | x <- [0..length dict - 1], isPrefixOf (dict!!x) str]

test_prefixes =
  [ prefixes "" dictionary == []
  , prefixes "appletree" []   == []
  , prefixes "appletree" ["ap", "apple", "tree", "pear"] == [(0, "ap"), (1, "apple")]
  , prefixes "babe" dictionary                    == [(98, "b")]
  ]

longest :: [(Int, String)] -> (Int, String)
longest prefs = maximumBy (compare `on` (\(x,y) -> length y)) prefs

test_longest =
  [ longest [(30, "a"), (20, "abc"), (15, "ab")]  == (20, "abc")
  , longest [(30, "a"), (20, "abc"), (15, "abc")] == (15, "abc")
  ]

instance MonadState Dictionary ((->) Dictionary) where
    get = \s -> s

munch :: MonadState Dictionary m => String -> m (Int, String, String)
munch str = do
        dict <- get
        let longst = longest (prefixes str dict)
        return (fst longst, snd longst, [str!!x | x <- [length (snd longst)..length str - 1]])

test_munch =
  [ evalState (munch "a")      ["a"]            == (0, "a", "")
  , evalState (munch "appletree") ["a"]            == (0, "a", "ppletree")
  , evalState (munch "peach") ["a", "ba", "b"] == (1, "ba", "be")
  ]

instance MonadState m (StateT Dictionary ((->) m)) where

append :: MonadState Dictionary m => String -> String -> m ()
append s "" = return ()
append s w = do
        dict <- get
        let newWord = s ++ (take 1 w)
        if (notElem newWord dict)
        then do
            put (dict++[newWord])
        else return ()

test_append =
  [ execState (append "a" "")   []         == []
  , execState (append "a" "")   dictionary == dictionary
  , execState (append "a" "bc") []         == ["ab"]
  , execState (append "a" "bc") ["ab"]     == ["ab"]
  ]

encode :: String -> WriterT [Int] (State Dictionary) ()
encode "" = return ()
encode w = do
        dict <- get
        let (a, b, c) = (munch w) dict
        if length dict < 256
        then do
            tell [a]
            put ((append b c) dict)
            encode c
        else return ()

test_encode =
  [ evalState (execWriterT (encode ""))         []         == []
  , evalState (execWriterT (encode "aaa"))      ["a"]      == [0, 1]
  , evalState (execWriterT (encode "aaaa"))     ["a"]      == [0, 1, 0]
  , evalState (execWriterT (encode "aaaaa"))    ["a"]      == [0, 1, 1]
  , evalState (execWriterT (encode "abababab")) ["a", "b"] == [0, 1, 2, 4, 1]
  , evalState (execWriterT (encode "aaabbbccc")) dictionary
    == [97, 128, 98, 130, 99, 132]
  ]

decode :: [Int] -> WriterT String (State Dictionary) ()
decode [] = return ()
decode [x] = do
    dict <- get
    tell (dict!!x)
decode (x:xs) = do
    dict <- get
    let f = dict!!x
    let s = if(length dict > head xs) 
            then dict!!head xs
            else f
    tell f
    put (append f s) dict
    decode xs

    test_decode =
  [ evalState (execWriterT (decode []))           []         == []
  , evalState (execWriterT (decode [0]))          ["a"]      == "a"
  , evalState (execWriterT (decode [0, 1, 1, 0])) ["a", "b"] == "abba"
  , evalState (execWriterT (decode [0, 1, 2, 0])) ["a", "b"] == "ababa"
  , evalState (execWriterT (decode [0, 1, 2, 4, 1])) ["a", "b"] == "abababab"
  , evalState (execWriterT (decode [97, 128, 98, 130, 99, 132])) dictionary
    == "aaabbbccc"
  ]

compress :: String -> [Int]
compress w = evalState (execWriterT (encode w)) dictionary

test_compress =
  [ compress ""          == []
  , compress "a"         == [97]
  , compress "aaa"       == [97, 128]
  , compress "aaabbbccc" == [97, 128, 98, 130, 99, 132]
  ]

decompress :: [Int] -> String
decompress list = evalState (execWriterT (decode list)) dictionary

test_decompress =
  [ decompress []                          == ""
  , decompress [97]                        == "a"
  , decompress [97, 128]                   == "aaa"
  , decompress [97, 128, 98, 130, 99, 132] == "aaabbbccc"
  ]

prop_compressDecompress :: String -> Bool
prop_compressDecompress w = do
    let tmp = [chr (div (ord x) 2) | x <- w]
    decompress (compress tmp) == tmp

compressFile :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
compressFile source target = do
    s <- readFile source
    let compressed = compress s
    let chars = [chr x | x <- compressed]
    writeFile target chars

decompressFile  :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
decompressFile  source target = do
    s <- readFile source
    let code = [ord x | x <- s]
    let decompressed = decompress code
    writeFile target decompressed

allTests = [test_dictionary, test_prefixes, test_longest, test_munch, test_append 
    ,test_encode
    --, test_decode, test_compress, test_decompress
    ]

main = do
    --quickCheck prop_compressDecompress
    print (allTests, and (concat allTests))
```

With this code I get the following error (referring to the use of put in "encode" and "decode" functions) :

> Main.hs@80:13-80:16 No instance for (MonadState () (StateT Dictionary Data.Functor.Identity.Identity)) arising from a use of put

I've tried to define this instance but the best I could achieve is a "functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations" error.
I know there is more simple solutions without Monads but I have to use them, also the types of the functions are not to be modified.

Could you give me any help about what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to write any instances. You're simply using `append` and `munch` in a wrong way.

`append` has type `MonadState Dictionary m => String -> String -> m ()`. 
If `f` and `s` are strings, then `append f s` yields a state-modifying action that eventually returns a `()`.

`put` has type `MonadState s m => s -> m ()`. `put` replaces the current state with the `s` argument.

In the light of this, `put (append f s) dict` makes little sense. You're supposed to supply `put` a single argument. And you don't have to do anything with `dict` there; a core point of using the State monad is that the state is left implicit, and there is no need to pass it around.

Also, `append f s` by itself already updates the state. So what you want here is simply `append f s`, instead of `put (append x y) dict`.

There's a similar error in `encode` with `munch`; it has a single `String` argument, so `(munch w) dict` is erroneous. Again, no need to touch `dict`. Also, because `munch w` yields a monadic result, you must bind the result with `<-` instead of `let`. So, you should replace `let (a, b, c) = (much w dict)` with `(a, b, c) <- munch w`.

Answer (score 1):

```
put ((append b c) dict)
```

looks wrong. `append` is already a monadic action, so it should be enough to use

```
append b c
```